# Workflow enter place listener

Tags: symfony

I'm working with the Workflow component in symfony 4.3. For my entity I have a marking property and a transition_contexts property. The transition_contexts is of JSON type like

```
[{"time": ..., "context":[all info I want], "new_marking" : "some_place", {etc...}]
```

for every transition made.
I want to set a transition_context also for the initial place called creation. For now, when I create a new object my transition_contexts looks like :

```
[{"time": ..., "context":[], "new_marking" : "creation"}]
```

For all other transitions I use the apply() function where I can set the context array, but for the initialisation with the initial place, I don't know how to do it.

I've read about listeners, so I tried

```
class FicheSyntheseTransitionListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $security;
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(Security $security, ManagerRegistry $em) 
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        //ManagerRegistry au lieu de EntityManagerInterface car on a plusieurs entityManager
        $this->connection = $em->getManager('fichesynthese');
    }

    public function addRedacteur(Event $event)
    {
        $context = $event->getContext();

        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        if ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
            $context['user'] = $user->getUsername();
        }

        $event->setContext($context);
        $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('fichesynthese')->flush();
    }


    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'workflow.fiche.entered.creation' => ['addRedacteur'],
        ];
    }
}
```

But it seems that it is not taken into account. Is there a way to achieve this ? A manual call to the function that set the initial marking ?
Thanks